# GWT eventhandler specifics

Tags: gwt

I am making a simple webui in gwt and I want to implement the following functionality: once the user clicks a checkbox, a new text area with some wording appears. When the user unchecks the textbox, the textarea disappears. Can anyone show me the implementation on how to do this?

Comment: I created a click handler for the checkbox, and basically will set the textarea visibility to true when the checkbox is clicked. However, I dont know how to check whether the state of the checkbox is true/false and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox has a [ValueChangeHander < Boolean >](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#addValueChangeHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeHandler)). You can use this to get the actual value, after the change.

There is also an [example](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html) to get the value within the clickhandler.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/HasValueChangeHandlers.html